# Correct measure unity for slope and aspect in order to work in QGIS with "r.sun.insoltime"

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, slope, aspect

I'm using QGIS 3.10 and I should create a raster that shows the hours of sunlight referring to a given day for my province. r.sun.insoltime (Fig. 1, sorry it's in Italian but I traslate) to work asks me to insert a terrain model (DTM), an aspect map ("esposizione" in Italian) and a slope map ("pendenza" in Italian). I already have the DTM, while I have to make the other two maps. The question is: which is the unit of measure accepted by the algorithm "r.sun.insoltime" for slope and aspect maps? Since under where the aspect layer is inserted there is written "a unique value of the orientation (aspect), 270 is south" I have to guess that the aspect must be in trigonometric angle (and then click on the box "return a trigonometric angle instead of the azimuth", Fig. 2), right? And the slope map (Fig. 3) instead must be calculated as a percentage or in degrees to work with r.sun.insoltime?

[image: fig1][image: fig2][image: fig3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This QGIS processing tool is based on the GRASS `r.sun` module. In the [manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.sun.html)  for that module there is a recommendation that you might take into account, and an explanation of how to create the slope and aspect rasters:

- The recommendation is to first create a horizon map using the GRASS `r.horizon` module.
- Regarding slope/aspect, you can create these from the original elevation raster using the GRASS module `r.slope.aspect`. From the man page for `r.sun`:

aspect=string
Name of the input aspect map (terrain aspect or azimuth of the solar panel) [**decimal degrees**]

slope=string
Name of the input slope raster map (terrain slope or solar panel inclination) [**decimal degrees**]

HTH